# Invert function: base 38 conversion

Tags: php

Can you tell me how the invert function for the following PHP function is?

```
<?php
function id2secure($old_number) {
    $alphabet_en = '1357902468acegikmoqsuwybdfhjlnprtvxz-_';
    $new_number = '';
    while ($old_number > 0) {
        $rest = $old_number%38;
        if ($rest >= 38) { return FALSE; }
        $new_number .= $alphabet_en[$rest];
        $old_number = floor($old_number/38);
    }
    $new_number = strrev($new_number);
    return $new_number;
}
echo id2secure(172293);
?>
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: 10 digits and 26 letters = 36, not 38 characters in your radix-set. Hence, the function you've posted won't work in the first place. Please reconsider your question and edit accordingly.

Comment: Also, just a FWIW, in practical applications (e.g., those nasty 25-character security keys, digits 0 and 1 are omitted, as are vowels. You'd be surprised how many times a randomly generated character string will contain a word that somebody finds objectionable!

Comment: @Bob Kaufman: Thanks, I forgot to add the - and the _ to the string. So now I have 38 characters.

Comment: @Bob Kaufman: Interesting, I didn't think about this yet. So I'll drop the 0 and 1 perhaps. How can I avoid these objectionable words? Not possible, is it?

Comment: @marco92w - the problem with a list of objectionable words is that you're bound to miss at least one of 'em, especially when it comes to cultures you may not be familiar with, as well as hypersensitive people who are just itching for a fight. No vowels means you can't form words. Problem solved!

Comment: @Bob Kaufman: Thank you very much, it's so simple :D So I'll just omit 0, 1, a, e, i, o, u and no objectionable words will be created, right?

Comment: @march92w - pretty much. No vowels = no words, mostly. I've considered ditching "Y" as an "I" sound-alike, but haven't. Taking umbrage to encountering SHYT or TYTS embedded in a string would be... extreme! Besides, "Y" is good enough for Microsoft, so it's good enough for me.

Comment: @Bob Kaufman Thank you so much. Now everything is clear! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is secure :) Took me a few minutes to crack it. Here you go,

```
function secure2id($new_number) {
        $alphabet_en = '1357902468acegikmoqsuwybdfhjlnprtvxz';
        $old_number = 0;
        $new_number = strrev($new_number);
        $len=strlen($new_number);
        $n=0;
        $base=1;
        while($n<$len){
            $c=$new_number[$n];
            $index = strpos($alphabet_en, $c);
            if ($index === false)
                 break;
            $old_number += $base * $index;
            $base *= 38;
            $n++;
        }
        return $old_number;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This works if you add the - and the _ at the end of $alphabet_en.

Comment: I thought the missing alphabet was a security feature :)

Comment: No, it wasn't :) Your function is 2.4 times as fast as ZenGeneral's.

Comment: Are you sure it's faster? ZenGeneral's has a pre-built lookup table. If you have bigger numbers, his should be faster.

Comment: Yes, I've been surprised about this, too. I've tested both functions with numbers up to 1,000,000,000. And your function is faster. :)

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tested this code, but it might work:

```
<?php function secure2id($sr)
{
  $s = strrev($sr);
  $alpha = '1357902468acegikmoqsuwybdfhjlnprtvxz';
  $alpha2num = array();
  $n = strlen($alpha);
  for($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++)
  {
    $alpha2num[$alpha[$i]] = $i;
  }
  $rez = 0;
  $n = strlen($s);
  $b = 1;
  for($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++)
  {
    $rez += $b * $alpha2num[$s[$i]];
    $b *= 38;
  }
  return $rez;
} ?>
```

`

Comment: Thank you. I've tested it: There's only one mistake. You have to write $b *= 38 instead of $b += 38.

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking how to convert base 38 to base 10?  The numerical algorithm is this:

1. Let N be the new number in base 10.  Set N to zero to start with.
2. Let X be the original number in base 38.
3. Multiply N by 38.
4. Let D be the most significant (leftmost) digit of X.
5. Let T be the value of D in base 10.
6. Add T to N.
7. Remove D from X (so the number X is now 1 digit shorter).
8. If X is empty, goto 10.
9. Goto 3.
10. Return N, which is now the fully converted base 10 number.

Now that you understand the math, it should be fairly straightforward to convert these steps to a PHP function.